# Is it possible to scaffold my controller using the .NET CLI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-cli

I'm following the ASP.NET Core tutorials at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model. I'm up to the *Scaffolding a Controller* section and I'm trying to create a controller from my model/DB context. However, when I follow the instructions as described in the guide, I receive this error:

[image]

I tried restoring the NuGet packages and creating a new project, but I'm still getting the same error. Is there a way to scaffold the controller using the .NET CLI? I've never seen one before, so I don't know how to write one up myself.

Thanks!

**edit:** I just tried @Prafull8495's answer and modified my project file as he instructed. The above error is no longer popping up, but now I'm hitting something else:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a csproj based ASP.NET Core project, you would need to make sure the below references are present (Targeting 1.0.x version of ASP.NET Core)

```
<ItemGroup>    
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(For projects targeting 1.1.x version of ASP.NET Core)

```
<ItemGroup>    
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0-msbuild3-final" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that the version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools` package remains the same in both the cases.

Also make sure that the below package is not referenced in the project as a PackageReference

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools

Comment: thank you for the advice. I modified my project file as you said and am no longer hitting that error, but I'm getting a different stack trace now (see the updated description).

Comment: @JamesKo Can you provide the package references in your project? I suspect there are some older packages that are directly referenced in the project that might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **project.json** then follow this approach.

To use Code Generator package, first you need to include it in `project.json` like this-

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build"
  },
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "type": "build"
  }
},
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now you can restore the packages using `dotnet restore` command. Once it is completed, you can scaffold controllers and views with the following command (*or from Visual Studio as shown in official guide*)-

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project . controller -name HelloController -m Author -dc WebAPIDataContext
```

The above command will generate controller with name HelloController in the root directory, and views for CRUD options inside Hello folder under Views folder. Please note that, above sample command will help you to create Controller with read write action using model and EF. Without model or dbcontext, it will create empty controller. You can use `--help` command line switch after controller parameter to get more options about controller generator.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to scaffold a controller using below command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TodoItemsController -async -api -m TodoItem -dc TodoContext -outDir Controllers
```